# cannot find module "firebase-functions"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I imported and downloaded: `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` using `npm i <package>` but it give me a lint error like: `cannot find module "firebase-functions"`. I also restarted *vscode*, but problem persists..

[image: screenhost 1] 
[image: screenhost 2]

---

Could it be problem with **webpack** or **tsconfig**?

Some important packages in **`package.json`**:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~5.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  }
```

}

Comment: Just one thought: what happens if you install the latest version of firebase-functions (which was subject to a major update in the last weeks, with release of V1.0)

Answer (score 19):

```
npm install firebase-functions
npm install firebase-admin
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The commands install the required software packages in the local project directory so that VSCode can see them @KalleRichter

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following commands:

```
firebase use --add
firebase init functions
```

To get your project. Sometimes, its a permission problem. What you can try is creating a new account on your computer and doing the same commands, that almost always works.

Answer (score 4):

I handled this problem with these steps. I don't really know whether exact solution is delete and initialize firebase functions again. Also I thought that problem is not specific only firebase-functions or firebase-admin. It can be missing node_modules packages.

1. delete node_modules in functions
2. `firebase init functions`. Update tsconfig and package.json and install dependencies.
3. restart vscode

Comment: Delete the node_modules and run npm install solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

@Shaybakov answer was the solution to my problem.

I recently switched the location of my project on my local machine. This meant that firebase libraries were not imported into the local directory and I either had to reconfigure the entire firebase CLl or just manually update the firebase libraries in the local directory with the commands that @Shaybakov stated.

```
npm install firebase-functions
npm install firebase-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1. npm install firebase-admin

step 2. npm install firebase-functions